# How to extract all From, To, Cc, Bcc emails from Gmail to store in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I am looking for some guidance on how to search an entire Gmail account for all email addresses that occur in From, To, Cc, and Bcc and extract those emails to store them into a Google Sheets document with one email per row.

Comment: You may take a look at the documentation,
 on [GmailApp.search() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery) with some [Gmail operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GmailApp.search() will let you search for a maximum of 500 threads. Each thread can have a maximum of 100 emails. So you will have to first iterate through the threads matching the search criteria, and thereafter the emails itself. Here's the code snippet

```
function printAllEmailFields(query) {

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query, 0, 500);

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messagesInThread = threads[i].getMessageCount();
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for(var j=0; j< messages.length; j++) {
      var from = messages[j].getFrom();
      var cc = messages[j].getCc();
      var bcc = messages[j].getBcc();
      var subject = messages[j].getSubject();
      Logger.log("subject: " + subject);
      Logger.log("from: " + from);
      Logger.log("cc: " + cc);
      Logger.log("bcc: " + bcc);
    }
  }
}
```